# How to find how a port has been forwarded from main server to hypver v vm

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, nat, hyper-v-server-2012

I must appologise for being a novice in server administration but I have somehow been given the responsibility and I have spent a long time reading up on this.

The issue I have is that the previous server admin set up certain ports which would forward onto a vm, eg we have our server SERVER1 which hosts two VMS VM1 and VM2. If you go to SERVER1:8112 you get to VM1.

I need to forward a new port on to VM2 however I don't want to break how this has originally been done, so I am trying to use the same method. There is no NAT set up from what I can see in the routing and remote access mmc, there is a virtual switch for Hypver V manager configured which both VMs are currently using. There are two network adapters, neither of this have share internet checkbox set however (this seemed to be a required precursor for setting up a NAT in each tutorial I have read through.

I was thinking it was possible to maybe use NETSH to list and see a rule for the port? Alas I have struggled to find out how to do this either.

So essentially, how can I find out how this has been done

Thanks for taking the time to read, I will supply any information if more is required. It is Windows Server 2012 running HyperV manager. Since I have never posted here before I can't embed an image so here is a screenshot of routing access mmc https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5S9w.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyper-V doesn't work like this. Forward ports as you would to physical servers - start looking at your firewalls or load balancing appliances.

Comment: This is it, I entirely forgot about the physical router, that NAT was set up to do it. Thank you very much for pointing out my obvious oversight